# error when try to boot:

Tags: boot

http://tau.rghost.ru/49221058/image.png 
I don't understand what should I write here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have tried to install Ubuntu and it is not starting and you are seeing this screen then you need to just reinstall it again. It is not seeing your hard drive or the boot sector. I wrote this answer for someone who had boot troubles. it may be a help to you to read it: [Error partitioning hard drive during installation of Ubuntu12.04.3 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355064/error-partitioning-hard-drive-during-installation-of-ubuntu12-04-3-lts/355106#355106)